# Why does x-overflow:hidden cause extra space below?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have two spans inside each other. On the inner span I have `overflow-x:hidden`. This causes extra space below the inner span. Why?

```
<span style="" class="yavbc-color-tip"><span style="">Some text</span></span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U92ue/

Note: I have only tested in latest Chrome.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> [**Visual formatting model - 9.4.1 Block formatting contexts**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)
>
> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as **inline-blocks**, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with **'overflow' other than 'visible'** (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

More specifically, a new block formatting context is established when the overflow property is changed. By default, an element's `vertical-align` property value is `baseline`. You can simply change this to something like `top` in order to fix this.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZRkY/)

```
span.yavbc-color-tip span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;   
    border: none;
    background-color:#005e8e;
    color:#7cd3ff;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* This gives extra space under this span. Why? */
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Notice this doesn't happen when the element's display isn't changed to `inline-block`? It doesn't occur with `inline` elements - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gs4ms/) demonstrating this.

Comment: Thanks Josh, indeed `vertical-align` on the inner span fixes it. Though I can't understand why. I can perhaps see why you tried this change, but the rules in 9.4.1 just talks about "new block formatting contexts". The inner span does not move vertically (or does it???) when adding `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: It's interesting that this also doesn't happen when the element's display is `block`. The spec quoted seems to separate "block containers that are not block boxes" (inline-blocks) and "block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible'", which doesn't strictly include this case (an `inline-block` with `overflow` other than `visible`).

Comment: This explanation is misleading: the behavior in question has nothing to do with Block Formatting Contexts (inline-blocks establish them regardless the `overflow` value). It's about the Inline Formatting Context where the element itself participates.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - Excellent.

Answer (score 9):

Despite the above quote in the accepted answer, this behavior has nothing to do with Block Formatting Context and with "block" part of the `inline-block` value at all. It's all about the "inline" part of it.

All `inline-*` elements participate in [the Inline Formatting Context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#inline-formatting). That means, they are placed inside the so called "line boxes" along with text and other inline-level elements. These elements and text are aligned with each other, so the height of each line box is calculated from the top of the highest element to the bottom of the lowest one.

By default, inline-level elements are aligned with the baseline of their fonts (see first line in the example below). Even if parent element has no actual text, the position of the baseline and the minimal height of the line box are calculated as if it had text (the spec calls this "imaginary" text the "strut" of the element). That's why the line box always has some space above the baseline (for the font ascenders and diacritics) and below it (for the font descenders) — see the second line of the example.

The tricky part for the `inline-block` elements is that `overflow` property changes *what is considered the baseline* for these elements (end of [section 10.8.1 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, *unless* it has either no in-flow line boxes *or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible',* in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

So, while technically the space below the baseline is *always* reserved, with default `overflow: visible`, the inline-block element is placed so that its text's baseline is aligned with the parent baseline, and its bottom part is moved below it. In many cases this makes this inline-block the lowest element in the line, so the space reserved for font descenders is not visible. However, changing the `overflow` value makes the whole element render above the baseline (like an `<img>` element), making all this space visible.

```css
p {
  margin: .5em;
  font: 32px/1.5 serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #888;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 12px/1 sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.ovh {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text with image <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x15"> and <span>two</span> <span>inline-block</span>s</p>

<p><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x15"> <span>only</span> <span>inline-blocks</span></p>

<p><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x15"> <span>regular</span>, the <span class="ovh">overflowed</span> trick</p>
```

In general, inline formatting is tricky. You can find a good explanation of some of its gotchas and surprises in this article: http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align.

I'd say that a good rule of thumb would be not using `display: inline-*` for its side effects, if you aren't really going to place the element inside the text. In the OPs example, the best solution would be to use `display: block` for the inner `span`, that doesn't involve any "magic" like line box calculation.

Comment: Old answer, but an excellent write-up. 