# Text overflow giving an unwanted bottom padding

Tags: html, css, overflow

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-text">Hello</div>
    <div class="child-price">$50</div>
</div>

.child-text,
.child-price {
    display: inline-block;
}
.child-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child-price {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjf96fpp/

For some reason when I give `.child-text` a hidden overflow it gives me an unwanted bottom padding. Please check jsfiddle link to see what I mean. If you remove `overflow:hidden;` the padding will disappear.

Comment: Just realized that it doesn't hide the excessive text at all. Bummer...

Answer (score 0):

**NEW EDIT**

Add `vertical-align: top` like this:

```
.child-text {    
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/sjf96fpp/4/)

For more details check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529369/why-does-x-overflowhidden-cause-extra-space-below)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, neither my fiddle, nor the one of yours will truncated the text for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

May I know what are you trying to achieve?

Would  you like to display child-text and child-price on one line? Child Text on the Left and Child Price on the right?

If so.

You could try the following:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod     
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
    <div class="child-price">$ 500.00</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: gray;
}

.child-text,
.child-price {
    float: left;
}

.child-text {
    width: 70%;
    height: 18px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
}

.child-price {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I added 70% and 30% Width's respectively for both  to stay on one line. This prevents child-price from being pushed to the next line. Please let me know if I got your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve, however I want the price to be visible 100% no matter how many digits it has and leave the rest of the block for the title (which should be truncated in case its name too long). In your example the price is limited by 30% of the block width..

Comment: You could try increasing the width of the price to a more reasonable price range though. make it like 50% for both <div> or 60% for price and 40% for the text. I hope someone out there could address your concern about dynamically adjusting the maximum width of the child-text depending on the width or length of child-price. Though my example could at least solve the problem of child-text not truncating and child-price being pushed off the line. As far as I know. In order to achieve truncation effect. You need to define a width for that specific element.

Comment: Maybe for the meantime, until you find a better solution. You could try and apply the 40% child-text and 60% child-price for the respective <div>s. I hope I had somehow helped you in  your concern.

Comment: I think I will try to play with display: table-cell. Thanks for you help though.