# overflow hidden moves another element

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap{
position:fixed;
left:0; top:45px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}

.datewrap{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}

.btnow{
display:inline-block;
background:green;
color:white;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>

<div class='datewrap'>323232</div>

<div class='btnow'>NOW</div>

</div>
```

Why is `btnow` moved down? It should be inline with `datewrap`.

If I remove `overflow:hidden` from `datewrap` - it's ok.

But I need `overflow:hidden` on `datewrap`.

Comment: add vertical-align property  to child div according to your requirement.  This will  help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use of `overflow:hidden`[overflow property evaluating to something other than visible] ,  the baseline is the bottom edge of the margin-box[insert margin-bottom and see result],so this element for align its baseline with baseline of other element move up a bit.

[image: Detail]

for fix use of `vertical-align: top;` like this:

```
.btnow {
  vertical-align: top;
  //Other css
}
```

```css
.wrap{
position:fixed;
left:0; top:45px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}

.datewrap{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}

.btnow{
display:inline-block;
background:green;
color:white;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>

<div class='datewrap'>323232</div>

<div class='btnow'>NOW</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey Try to explain also why you added this and what is the meaning of this for readers.

Comment: @NitinBisht, `why you added...` - what?

Comment: @blueSky Why vertical-align: top; was added and what it does?

Comment: @NitinBisht, seems nobody knows. I can just say - CSS is full of such misterious behaviours.

Comment: vertical-align: top; align divs in same level.

Comment: @Ehsan, but they should be aligned by default, isn't it?

Comment: @blueSky, yes if `.datewrap` have `display:inline`

Comment: @blueSky this is honestly not the best solution. if you increase the height of `.wrap`, both `.datewrap` and `.btnow` will stick to the top of `.wrap` instead of remaining in the middle of it... unless that is what you want?

Comment: @Ehsan, no, if .datewrap have `display: inline -block` - they should be aligned also, because both elments are without `vertical-align` specified.

Comment: @blueSky you replied to the wrong person. all i'm saying is that this likely is not the best solution to your problem...

Comment: @Anthony, ok.bay.

Comment: May be this explanation can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51088033/2533215

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` really shouldn't be used to position elements. There are far better ways to achieve this.

I don't know why `overflow` is causing it to "teeter-totter", but below is some code to fix this.

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* and if you want to make sure the elements are always aligned vertically */
  align-items: center;
  /* remember: justify-content will always control the same direction as the flex
  ** box; so, if the flex box is a row, justify-content will control the horizontal
  ** spacing and align-items will control the vertical spacing, but if the flex box
  ** is a column justify-content will control the vertical and align-items will
  ** control the horizontal. */
  

  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  background: gold;
}

.datewrap, .btnow {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.datewrap{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btnow{
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>

<div class='datewrap'>323232</div>

<div class='btnow'>NOW</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align` CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

Reference Link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: gold;
}

.datewrap, .btnow  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.datewrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.btnow {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>

  <div class='datewrap'>323232</div>

  <div class='btnow'>NOW</div>

</div>
```

**Note:** 
If you are writing code in real-time, you need to minimize your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap{
position:fixed;
left:0; top:45px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}

.datewrap{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}

.btnow{
display:inline-block;
background:green;
color:white;
margin:0 5px;
border:2px solid red;
position:inherit; 
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>

<div class='datewrap'>323232</div>

<div class='btnow'>NOW</div>

</div>
```