# Remove extra bottom padding on CSS columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, padding, margin

I have a CSS column layout.

I find however, that there is an unnecessary gap at the bottom (indicated by the pink arrow in screengrab).

This gap disappears if I remove `display: inline-block` from the CSS, but then some of the `<section>` elements break in two. I've also tried using `break-inside: avoid` but it appears to do nothing at all.

Is there a fix for this?

```
<div class="feed-index">
    <div class="feed">
        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

.feed-index .feed {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 40px;
}

.feed-index .feed > section {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your CSS for `.feed-index .feed > section`

The reason is your `overflow: hidden;` actually changes the block.  See more info here: [Why does x-overflow:hidden cause extra space below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529369/why-does-x-overflowhidden-cause-extra-space-below)